# syntax for inserting checkbox data from php page to database

Tags: php

I have a  php form with some text box, list of radio buttons and checkboxes with a submit button.
I want to enter the values inputted  in this php form to a database.The textbox as well as the radiobutton values and only one of my checkbox values are geting entered.I have a single column for entering the checkbox values in my query.I would like to know the syntax for entering all the selected checkbox values into that single column separated by commas.

Comment: You don't want to store them in one column. You could create a connection table, or something, it will save you some headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work. A name with "[]" at the end of it will return an array to $_POST. Should be ok with some testing.

HTML

```
<!-- open method="post" form here -->
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name[]" value="2" />
```

PHP

```
<?php

// INSERT THIS VALUE INTO COLUMN FOR A COMMA DELIMITED LIST
$checkbox_values = implode(',', $_POST['checkbox_name']);

?>
```

Edit: You'll need to test for the array though, as if no boxes are checked, $_POST['checkbox_name'] will not be an array.